# Implementation of MATLAB's `im2col`

Tags: performance, c, matlab, vectorization, openmp

The function [`im2col`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) in MATLAB is very useful to vectorize Patch based Image Processing algorithms. The problem is the function isn't optimized and doesn't use C Code. I'm trying to build efficient C code for that.

This is the code I created:

```
function [ mColumnImage ] = ImageToColumns( mInputImage, blockRadius )
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
% [ mColumnImage ] = ImageToColumns( mInputImage, blockRadius )
%   Creates an column image from the sliding neighborhood in mInpuImage
% Input:
%   - mInputImage           -   Input image.
%                               Matrix, 1 Channels, Floating Point
%   - blockRadius        -      Local Window Radius.
%                               Scalar, Floating Point, {1, 2, ..., inf}.
% Output:
%   - mColumnImage          -   Input image.
%                               Matrix, 1 Channels, Floating Point, [0, 1]
% Remarks:
%   1.  Prefixes:
%       -   'm' - Matrix.
%       -   'v' - Vector.
%   2.  C
% TODO:
%   1.  I
%   Release Notes:
%   -   1.0.000     22/08/2014  R
%       *   First release version.
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %

numRows = size(mInputImage, 1);
numCols = size(mInputImage, 2);

blockSize = (2 * blockRadius) + 1;

numPixelsToProcess = (numRows - blockSize + 1) * (numCols - blockSize + 1);

mColumnImage = zeros((blockSize * blockSize), numPixelsToProcess);

colImageColIdx = 0;

for iColIdx = (blockRadius + 1):(numCols - blockRadius)
    for jRowIdx = (blockRadius + 1):(numRows - blockRadius)
        colImageColIdx = colImageColIdx + 1;
        colImageRowIdx = 0;
        for kPixelColIdx = -blockRadius:blockRadius
            for lPixelRowIdx = -blockRadius:blockRadius
                colImageRowIdx = colImageRowIdx + 1;
                mColumnImage(colImageRowIdx, colImageColIdx) = mInputImage((jRowIdx + lPixelRowIdx), (iColIdx + kPixelColIdx));
            end
        end
    end
end


end
```

It is MATLAB code written in C style. Imagine it was C code: what would you do make it faster? What would you do to allow compiler optimizations (loop unrolling, vectorization, parallelization, etc...)?

I posted vanilla C code I created and have a few questions about it:

1. How can I make the memory access more efficient (hence make the code faster)?
2. Any place to utilize vectorization?
3. How can I assist the compiler and tell it no aliasing will happen?
4. What would be the right way to utilize OpenMP?

Comment: @CrisLuengo, The reason the inner loop are on the rows is because MATLAB is Column Major.

Comment: Sorry, I must have had a brain fart when I wrote that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a valid C code which implements the above:

```
void ImageToColumns(float* mO, float* mI, int numRows, int numCols, int blockRadius)
{
    int blockSize, blockNumElements, colImageColIdx, colImageRowIdx;
    int ii, jj, kk, ll;

    blockSize           = (2 * blockRadius) + 1;
    blockNumElements    = blockSize * blockSize;
    colImageRowIdx      = -1;

    for (ii = blockRadius; ii < (numRows - blockRadius); ii++)
    {
        for (jj = blockRadius; jj < (numCols - blockRadius); jj++)
        {
            colImageRowIdx = colImageRowIdx + 1;
            colImageColIdx = -1;

            for (kk = -blockRadius; kk <= blockRadius; kk++)
            {
                for (ll = -blockRadius; ll <= blockRadius; ll++)
                {
                    colImageColIdx = colImageColIdx + 1;
                    mO[(colImageRowIdx * blockNumElements) + colImageColIdx] = mI[((ii + kk) * numCols) + jj + ll];
                }

            }
        }
    }


}
```

Clearly this a memory bounded algorithm.